# RegEx notation with S?

Tags: regex

Hey really quick. What does the `\s` and the `+` mean in the following regex statement?:

`->\s+(.*)( |;)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` is a whitespace character, and `+` means "at least one".

Answer (score 0):

`\s` will match a white space, tab, or line break.

`+` means there must be at least one but could repeat.

In other words, it will match any part of a string that has consecutive characters that are anything that `\s` will match.

Check out this website. It has really good for RegEx reference.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html